# Open a UIView before UITabbar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, loginview

I am creating an app with tab bar. I want a login screen to appear before tab bar if the user is not logged in.
So I connected the tab bar controller with the login view controller using segue.

I am running this code in tab bar controller:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{


if([user isEqualToString:@""] || user==nil){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toLoginVC" sender:self];
}
```

but the tab bar is appear and then the view. I tried to use the viewWillAppear but I am getting an error?
Any ides how to create the login screen?

Answer (score 0):

More information would be useful, but judging by your description, I would change some settings in your segue.

First, I assume you have a modal segue that covers the whole screen, including the tab bar. If not, you should change your segue to modal, as this is the "proper" abstraction for a login screen like you are describing.

Second, if you uncheck the "Animates" box in the attributes inspector, it should appear right away.